# JPG Images Lose Quality When DES Encrypting

Tags: python, image, encryption

I'm using the PyCrypto Python library to attempt to encrypt a .jpg image file with a password. However, whenever I decrypt the file and open it, it comes out looking almost like a rainbow, and although you can vaguely see the original image, it looks nothing like it. I was wondering where the quality is being lost? My guess is that when I pad the file (you know, so that the length is a multiple of 8, which is what DES needs), I do so with a '{' character, and when I decrypt the file, I use decryptedFileText.replace('{',''), you know, to get rid of the pad characters, but at the same time, I may be removing other '{' characters crucial to the image quality. I was wondering if anyone knew a way of padding files that could get around this, or if I'm missing the problem entirely.

Comment: If you remove '{' bytes within the image, then the remaining pixel data will be offset and interpreted incorrectly. That's why your output is distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're padding the file, make sure the pad character is not the same as the final byte in the file.  When removing the padding, remove the bytes from the end of the file that have the same value, up to 8 in a row.  If the original file's length is a multiple of 8, add 8 pad bytes, different from the final value in the file.

If you pad the file this way, don't use replace(), which will operate on the entire file, but use something like `decryptedFileText = decryptedFileText.rstrip(decryptedFileText[-1])`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I should've thought to do this. The question is how can you know how many of the chars at the end of the file are pads and which are actually part of the file? So you're saying I should check the last char in the file and change the pad accordingly? The thing is I'm padding a group of images. How would I tag the file with the correct pad character?

Comment: Check the last byte in the file, and choose any other value for your pad character.  If the length of the file is a multiple of 8, add 8 pad bytes; otherwise, pad until the length is a multiple of 8.  For removing the pad, you don't need to know what it is; just remove values from the end of the file which match each other.  This guarantees that the file ends with up to 8 pad characters of the same value, which are different from the last non-pad byte of the unpadded file.